# opening a new S3Client client with PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk

I have been given the following code from the SDK documentation.

```
$s3 = /SDK/Aws/S3/S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'eu-geo',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'Active Key',
        'secret' => 'Secret Key'
    ]
]);
```

However, when I try to run it (with the correct keys) I get an error on line 1 as an uncaught error. It must be something simple but I am new to this SDK. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try with \SDK\Aws\S3\S3Client pls

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion it has moved me forward but I now get the error.

Comment: Many thanks for you suggestion but I now get the error "unexpected '/' ". Very confusing as this is what I would have expected to be correct so the system knows where to find the file.

Comment: What is the namespace of your file, how did you install the sdk ? 
The first \ you can try without it

Comment: I have tried doing without the first '/' and this resulted in the following error "unexpected 'pls' (T_STRING) " so I removed the 'pls' but then got the original error back again

Comment: Oh "pls" was just "please" sorry for the misunderstanding. How did you install the SDK ?

Comment: I downloaded the SDK as a zip file then unzipped it and copied it to the root directory. This was one of the methods of installation I was given. There was no actual installation or setup file. There is a readme.md file which says to just unzip it.